# How to embed large (max 10Mb) text files into an Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

What is the best way to store a large text file (max 10Mb) in an Excel file?

I have a couple of requirements:

1. It has to be embedded so that the excel file can be moved and sent to a different computer and all the text files will follow.
2. It needs to be done from a macro.
3. And a macro needs to be able to read the file contents after it has been embedded.

I already tried to store it by breaking the text into several chunks enough small to fit into a cell (~32 000 chars), but it didn't work. After my macro had inserted the first 150 000 characters it gave me an "Out of Memory" error.

I remember seeing one web page with a couple of options for this I but cannot find it anymore. Any suggestions are most welcome. I will try them out if you are not sure if it works or not.

Comment: CustomXMLPart (2010+)?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865361(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: CustomXMLPart sounds interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple CustomXMLPart example:

```
Sub CustomTextTester()

    Dim cxp1 As CustomXMLPart, cxp2 As CustomXMLPart
    Dim txt As String

    'read file content
    txt = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile( _
                                      "C:\_Stuff\test.txt").readall()

    'Add a custom XML part with that content
    Set cxp1 = ThisWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Add("<myXMLPart><content><![CDATA[" & txt _
                                               & "]]></content></myXMLPart>")

    Debug.Print cxp1.SelectSingleNode("myXMLPart/content").FirstChild.NodeValue

End Sub
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216070%28v=office.12%29.aspx says that Excel 2007 supports CustomXMLParts. I think this is a very promising solution.

Comment: The stinks, Mac VBA does not know about CustomXMLPart. Why Microsoft makes VBA in different platforms so different from each other. I quess I need to have the .txt file alongside the Excel file on mac.

Answer (score 3):

It would likely be best to simply save the .txt file alongside the Excel file, and have the macro pull the text as needed from that folder. To read more on importing files see this:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/vba-code-to-import-multiple-text-files-from/525bd388-0f7d-4b4a-89f9-310c67227458

Keeping the .txt within the Excel file itself is not necessary and will likely make it harder to transfer files in the long run. For example, if you cannot e-mail a file larger than 10MB, then you can simply break your .txt file in half and e-mail separately - using a macro which loads the text into Excel locally.

Comment: If it would be just me or my team working with the Excel file then this could be an option. Unfortunately this spreadsheet is going to be used by consumer level users. That is why the file needs to be able to handle it all by it self.

Comment: Even if a consumer level user has this file, you should be able to package your offering together with your .txt file alongside your .xlsx file. If the 'consumers' still work in a location which accesses a common work network, the consider even having that file in a public location. You wouldn't need to send the .txt around at all (although the user would need to have access to the network at the point of using the Excel file).

Comment: Though I don't have much experience with this, you can rename a .xlsx file to .zip and it will allow you to open it like a folder. You can place files inside that zipped package, and rename to .xlsx. This will technically allow you to save it as a single file, but I personally don't have experience referring to "internal" files like this within a macro. It's basically the same as what I suggested except that the file size again because a limit if you are emailing the Excel file around.

Comment: @GradeEhBacon it's a good idea to work with .xlsx as .zip, but seems there are issues like validation errors (unreadable content) and file access lock (while file is opened with Excel), that couldn't be solved unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the method shown below. It uses `Caption` property of `Label` object located on a worksheet for data storage. So you can create a number of such containers with different names.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sText
    ' create special hidden sheet for data storage
    If Not IsSheetExists("storage") Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
            .Name = "storage"
            .Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End With
    End If
    ' create new OLE object TypeForms.Label type as container
    AddContainer "test_container_"
    ' read text from file
    sText = ReadTextFile("C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\tmp\tmp.txt", 0)
    ' put text into container
    PutContent "test_container_", sText
    ' retrieve text from container
    sText = GetContent("test_container_")
    ' show length
    MsgBox Len(sText)
    ' remove container
    RemoveContainer "test_container_"
End Sub

Function IsSheetExists(sSheetName)
    Dim oSheet
    For Each oSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If oSheet.Name = sSheetName Then
            IsSheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsSheetExists = False
End Function

Sub AddContainer(sName)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("storage").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1")
        .Visible = False
        .Name = sName
    End With
End Sub

Sub RemoveContainer(sName)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("storage").OLEObjects.Item(sName).Delete
End Sub

Sub PutContent(sName, sContent)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("storage").OLEObjects.Item(sName).Object.Caption = sContent
End Sub

Function GetContent(sName)
    GetContent = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("storage").OLEObjects.Item(sName).Object.Caption
End Function

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, iFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, iFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Some sources say that there would be a maximum length of 1024 or 2048 characters for the Label Caption. Do you have an experience that there could be more than 2048 characters in the caption?

Comment: For my system `ActiveX Control Label`, which used in code above, has capacity approx. 90 MB per element, for reference: `Forms Control Label` has limitation of 32 kB per element, and @TimWilliams' `CustomXMLPart` capacity is approx. 50 MB per element. I must confess that `CustomXMLPart` is faster, native, and has higher compression ratio for result .xlsx file.